# Reference to label of third line in Verbatim env jumps to wrong position

Tags: hyperref, fancyvrb

I want to

1. make reference to lines in `Verbatim` environment provided by `fancyvrb` pacakge, and
2. make the reference a hyperlink which jumps to the right position where corresponding label is defined, with the help of `hyperref`

If simply use `fancyvrb` with `hyperref`, these references all jump to `hyperref`'s named destination `Doc-Start` (use the following MWE). Thus I modified `\FV@refstepcounter` to directly use `\steprefcounter`.

This modification works on the label of first and second line of `Verbatim` env. But, from the third line, `\ref{vrb:n}` jumps to the position of `\label{vrb:n-1}` (use the following MWE).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\FV@refstepcounter#1{%
%  \PackageError{FV}{pre step: \the\c@FancyVerbLine, \@currentHref}{}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
%  \PackageError{FV}{post step: \the\c@FancyVerbLine, \@currentHref}{}%
}

%% original def
%\def\FV@refstepcounter#1{%  
%  \stepcounter{#1}
%  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#1\endcsname\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}%
%}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
1. For n = 1 or 2, \ref{vrb:n} jumps to destination \label{n}.
2. For n >= 3, \ref{vrb:n} jumps to destination \label{n - 1}.
\end{verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},numbers=left]
  first   \label{vrb:1}
  second  \label{vrb:2}
  third   \label{vrb:3}
  forth   \label{vrb:4}
  fifth   \label{vrb:5}
  sixth   \label{vrb:6}
\end{Verbatim}

\ref{vrb:1}, \ref{vrb:2}, \ref{vrb:3}, \ref{vrb:4}, \ref{vrb:5}, and \ref{vrb:6}
\newpage\null
\end{document}
```

[image: output of mwe]

This problem is re-producible with either pdflatex, lualatex or xelatex contained in texlive 2019. And I have latest `fancyvrb` and `hyperref` installed.

#### What I have investigated

1. `.aux` shows that every label creates distinct hyper target, e.g., `\label{vrb:3}` creates `\newlabel{vrb:3}{...}{1}{}{FancyVerbLine.3}{}`.
2. Contents of output PDF shows that the coordinates of named destination of `FancyVerbLine.2` and `FancyVerbLine.3` are the same, which causes the jump-to-wrong-position problem.
3. Un-comment the lines of `\PackageError` will show that the counter stepping is only taken inside `\FV@refstepcounter`.
4. Further more, `listings` and `hyperref` works ok.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% use example in `texdoc listings`, sec. 8
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
for i:=maxint to 0 do(*@\label{lst:1}@*)
begin                (*@\label{lst:2}@*)
{ comment }          (*@\label{lst:3}@*)
end;
\end{lstlisting}
\ref{lst:1}, \ref{lst:2} and \ref{lst:3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is related about `fancyvrb` only. `hyperref` makes the "internal info" obvious, but the info is unchanged. The key info that the mwe in question provides (and I am still confusing about) is,

- the ypos of "FancyVerbLine.2" is always 10pt lower than that of "FancyVerbLine.1" (no matter how much the font size is set outside `Verbatim` env), and
- ypos of "FancyVerbLine.3" is always the same as "FancyVerbLine.2"

By moving `\FV@StepLineNo` from the early `\FV@@PreProcessLine` to the very late command `\FV@ListProcessLine` (which does the actual output line-by-line), this problems seems solved. I am not sure if this patch would cause any new problems.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\FV@refstepcounter\refstepcounter

\patchcmd\FV@@PreProcessLine
  {\FV@StepLineNo}
  {}
  {}{\fail}

\patchcmd\FV@ListProcessLine
  {\kern\leftmargin}
  {\FV@StepLineNo\kern\leftmargin}
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left]
first
second
third
forth
fifth
sixth
\end{Verbatim}

\def\xlink#1{\hyperlink{FancyVerbLine.#1}{#1}}
\xlink{1}, \xlink{2}, \xlink{3}, \xlink{4}, \xlink{5}, \xlink{6}
\newpage\null
\end{document}
```

Some explanations, or personal understanding:

1. `hyperref` redefined `\refstepcounter` to

   1. update `\@currentHref` (which stores `FancyVerbLine.<n>` in the mwe) and
   2. write named destination to PDF (more general speaking, the driver).
2. When named destinations are written, indirect coordinates are used. For xetex + (x)dvipdfmx, `@xpos` and `@ypos` are used (instead of direct coordinate numbers), which are inherited from `dvipdfm`.
3. Hence, the problem is, `\refstepcounter{FancyVerbLine}` is called at a wrong position. One can check this with the savepos module of `zref` package, and without loading of `hyperref`. (see the following example)
4. `fancyvrb` uses `\FV@StepLineNo` as a wrapper of `\refstepcounter`, in order to support options like `numberblanklines`

```latex
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\makeatletter
\let\FV@refstepcounter\refstepcounter

\newcounter{zRef}
\newcommand\showYPos[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{zRef}%
  \zsavepos{curr:\arabic{zRef}}%
  \def\x{\the\expandafter\numexpr\zposy{curr:\arabic{zRef}}/65536\relax}
  \PackageError{FV}{#1, line: \the\c@FancyVerbLine, ref \the\c@zRef, ypos \x}{}%
}

\def\FV@@PreProcessLine{%
  \showYPos[before step]%  ypos is wrong steped
  \FV@StepLineNo
  \FV@Gobble
  \expandafter\FV@ProcessLine\expandafter{\FV@Line}}

\def\FV@ListProcessLine#1{%
  \hbox to \hsize{%  inside this hbox, ypos is ok
    \FV@StepLineNo
%    \showYPos[inside hbox]%  ypos is ok
    \kern\leftmargin
    \hbox to \linewidth{%
      \FV@LeftListNumber
      \FV@LeftListFrame
      \FancyVerbFormatLine{#1}\hss
      \FV@RightListFrame
      \FV@RightListNumber}%
    \hss}%
%  \showYPos[outside hbox]%  ypos is wrong steped
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fontsize{20}{50}\selectfont
\begin{Verbatim}
a
b
c
d
e
f
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```